# SQL Server rowlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Using SQL Server I need to know if it is actually possible to use `RowLock` for an Update statement.

I have the following problem: a table can not accept change in the same record at the same time, in different records there are no problems. For this I do a `SELECT` with `UPDLOCK` / `NOWAIT` for the desired record, and if no error is returned the change is allowed. The problem is that if a user A starts changing table record 1, then user B starts editing table record 2, user A will only be able to complete its update when user B also completes. It will stay locked waiting.

I read many topics about it but none helped at that point. It seems to me that the `Update` operation tries to lock the whole table. They are different lines, there should be some way to control it.

I have this scenario:

Step 1: start a transaction;

Step 2: Before to start an update I need to lock the record:
'select * from Mytable with (updlock, nowait) where Id = MyId';

If no one exception, the record is locked;

Step 3: My update is done:
'update MyTable set some_field = some_value where Id = MyId';

Step 4: commit transaction;

The problem is:

1 - User A, starts an update on record 1 (Id = 1);

2 - User B, starts an update on record 2 (Id = 2);

1 - User A needs to execute your update. HERE IS THE PROBLEM, until user B not commit or rollback your transaction, user A needs to wait;

Comment: Locking is pessimistic concurrency: if an update can't happen, it'll wait until it can. You may find snapshot isolation more to your liking, where updates will fail and have to be retried (or ignored, as you please) if it turns out another update has happened in the meantime.

Comment: There is rowlock and tablock, depending on how you access the data the lock might escalate.

Comment: I fail to see the usefulness of step 2. Normally, you'd create a transaction (step1) and jump to update the record (step 3). Why do you need step 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to turn off the `ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS` in the clustered/nonclustered index. If you do not have any clustered/nonclustered index, you can simply add new one! BUT be aware off the row level locking side effects

```
ALTER INDEX YOURINDEX ON YOUR_TABLE SET ( ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF )
```

**Reproduce the Problem**

I have two concurrent sessions. Session 1, tries to run the following code:

```
BEGIN TRAN

   UPDATE dbo.tblTest  SET Title='aa' WHERE id =1

   WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:59'

   ROLLBACK
```

Session 2 tries to run the following code:

```
UPDATE dbo.tblTest  SET Title='bb' WHERE id =2
```

I execute the Session 1 first and then execute the session 2, we see that both sessions stuck in Executing...In fact Session 2 will wait for Session 1 to release the lock!

to overcome this problem I Alter my Index and turn off the `ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS` using following code:

```
ALTER INDEX YOURINDEX ON YOUR_TABLE SET ( ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF )
```

Now retry the scenario...Now while session 1 is in Executing phase, but session 2 executes its statement regardless of the lock on the session's 1 records

Read more about it: https://littlekendra.com/2016/02/04/why-rowlock-hints-can-make-queries-slower-and-blocking-worse-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Túlio I reproduced your scenario and it just work fine for me after turning off the page level locking in Index. Check your index again...

Comment: this now works. I don't mentioned but in my table one of the fields, a datetime field, has a trigger. When I disabled that trigger, the solution works.